# Hibernate and database functions with packages

Tags: java, database, oracle, hibernate, function

I call a function in oracle that is something like this: `FOO.PACKAGE_NAME.function(param)` and it works fine using `session.getNamedQuery("alias")...`.

Now I want to be able to call this same function, but internally using some Hibernate feature to change `FOO.PACKAGE_NAME.function(param)` to `PACKAGE_NAME.function(param)`.

Is it possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `FOO` is the database schema, then you can try setting the global schema like this:

```
<property name="hibernate.default_schema" value="FOO"/>
```

You can reference the default schema using the [`{h-schema}`](https://vladmihalcea.com/how-to-resolve-the-hibernate-global-database-schema-and-catalog-for-native-sql-queries/) placeholder:

```
@NamedNativeQuery(
    name = "my_query",
    query =
        "select {h-schema}PACKAGE_NAME.function( :param ) " +
        "from dual ",
    resultClass = MyResult.class
)
```

Comment: For schema this will work, but if I need to change the package name? Is it possible?
I need some flexibility to change this just to run my tests.

Comment: Hibernate has no notation of Oracle function package names. So, unless you want to vary the schema, there's nothing you can do about it.